# Is it possible to instantiate a second class when the first gets instantiated without using a constructor?

Tags: php, oop

Sorry, for the badly phrased title. I don't know much object-oriented PHP, so, I couldn't come up with a better title (or an answer to my problem!).

Ok, so, I have something like this:

```
Class foo{
    var $hello;
    function foo(){
    }
}

Class customfoo extends foo{
    //No Constructor
}
```

Now, I wrote another class, let's call it `customclass` and I want to use it in the `customfoo` class. But, I don't just want to use it in the `customfoo` class, I want it to be created as soon as the `customfoo` class is created.

Ordinarily, I presume, you would just use the constructor for this, so something like:

```
 Class customfoo extends foo{
    var $custom;
    function customfoo(){
        $this->custom = new customclass();   
    }
}
```

However, `customfoo` is a child class, so, I think the constructor would replace the constructor of the parent class, and I don't want that to happen. So, how can I make a class `customclass` when `customfoo` is first started? I guess, I could just write an arbitrary function and call it via some other function (that I am sure gets executed early on), but it would be nice to at least know how to do the above.

Comment: In PHP the constructor of a class is `__construct()`. Using a function with the same name of the class as a constructor is depreciated and works for backwards compatability only. You should no longer use it.

Comment: @vascowhite Yup, I don't intend to. The code I was working on had it already written like that, so I subconsciously copied it over.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php this might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should name your counstructors as `__construct`.

As you have pointed out, the constructor you write will overwrite the parent's one, but you can always call it from the child class, like this:

```
Class customfoo extends foo{
    var $custom;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->custom = new customclass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, yeah, you are right about the `_construct` thing. The code was already written, so I left it as is.
As for your solution, huh, that's interesting. So, uhmm, is parent a keyword, or do I put the parent classes name there?

Comment: No, parent is a reserved keyword. You can find more information on the php manual: http://www.php.net/__construct

Comment: @zermy it looks like you should read this http://us2.php.net/oop or a good book/web site on OOP with PHP. There are lots of good tutorials out there.